How to download docx file with django\react [EDITED: axios]?
I try to download test.docx but  file size and content incorrect.
As example source file size is 14kb, downloaded 22kb
Source file contain table(if this important)
But it's work correct with pdf and txt
view.py
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class TestDownloadView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        filename = "./test.docx"
        with open(filename, "rb") as blank:
            content = blank.read()
            response = HttpResponse(
                content,
                content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
            )
            response["Content-Length"] = len(content)
            response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=test.docx"
            return response

App.tsx
function App() {

        const dload = () => {
                axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
                        .then(response => {
                                const type = response.headers['content-type']
                                const href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: type }));
                                const link = document.createElement('a');
                                link.href = href;
                                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.docx');
                                document.body.appendChild(link);
                                link.click();
                                document.body.removeChild(link);
                                URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
                        })
        }
        return (
                <>
                        <button onClick={dload}> Click </button>
                </>
        )
}

I already try different content-type.
Edited
So the problem not in Django.
I rewrite axios to fetch like this:
                fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000', { method: "POST" })
                        .then(response => response.blob())
                        .then(blob => {
                                const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                const link = document.createElement('a');
                                link.href = href;
                                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.docx');
                                document.body.appendChild(link);
                                link.click();
                                document.body.removeChild(link);
                                URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
                        })

And this work. But i still need axios solution or any idea. Whats wrong?

Thanks @KJ I appreciate your help. Topic that you give me was informative and show me that i right with django. As I found problem was with axios.

If someone find this helpful this is solution
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000', {}, { responseType: "blob" }) 
// axios post with empty data and response type(important`)
    .then(response => {
        const type = response.headers['content-type']
        console.log(response.headers)
        const href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: type }));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = href;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.docx');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
})

